# Why does react-calendar-timeline itemRender prop not work with useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-calendar-timeline

[react-calendar-timeline](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline) allows for a prop `itemRenderer` which can be used to render custom timeline `items`. This works as it should until I try to call the `useState` hook inside the `itemRenderer` method.

I'm assuming that the error is occurring because I am trying to call the `useState` hook inside of a component which is implemented using an older version of react. Assuming that is true, does anyone know how to fix without using a class component to implement my custom item renderer?

Here is a [minimum reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-cdn-slkxnd?file=/src/CustomItemRenderer.jsx). Comment out the line in `CustomItemRenderer.jsx` and refresh the sandbox to see the error.

### Code

**CustomItemRenderer:**

```
const CustomItemRenderer = ({ item, itemContext, getItemProps }) => {
  // Uncomment the line below to see the error
  // const [someCustomState, setSomeCustomState] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div {...getItemProps(item.itemProps)}>Custom {itemContext.title}</div>
  );
};

export default CustomItemRenderer;
```

**Usage in Timeline:**

```
<Timeline
  items={items}
  groups={groups}
  defaultTimeStart={defaultTimeStart}
  defaultTimeEnd={defaultTimeEnd}
  itemRenderer={CustomItemRenderer}
/>
```

Comment: Next time include the relevant code in the question in addition to the sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks can only be called by components and custom hooks. You are trying to call `useState` from a standard function. Instead return a function that renders `CustomItemRenderer` as a standard component ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-pond-xryrvn?file=/src/CustomItemRenderer.jsx)):

```
const CustomItemRenderer = ({ item, itemContext, getItemProps }) => {
  const [someCustomState, setSomeCustomState] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div {...getItemProps(item.itemProps)}>Custom {itemContext.title}</div>
  );
};

export default props => <CustomItemRenderer {...props} />; // render the component
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I'm confused though. Why is it that changing the return in this way converts it to a component instead of a standard function?

Comment: It doesn't convert it to a component l. It renders the component as JSX inside an anonymous function.

Comment: Wasn't it already rendering as jsx? How does returning it from an anonymous function suddenly start rendering jsx?

Comment: By doing this `<CustomItemRenderer {...props} />` instead of calling it as a function like this `CustomItemRenderer(props)` (which is what the `Timeline` does).